Php is installed but not loading in Apache2 version 24.04
So, I have Apache2 installed and after upgrading from 23.10 apparently PHP code is shown in the browser rather than executing.
I installed PHP 8.3, and tried loading the module to get this error.
root@p7-1268c:/var/www/html# a2enmod php
ERROR: Module php does not exist!

How do I fix this?

After messing around, these commands worked as sudo.
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod php8.3
systemctl restart apache2

